# Opposite function of this mime type - /export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Planning to create a python script that can handle auto import and update the spreadsheet I have script that can download the spread and transfer it to my local folder.

May I know what is the import function of this?

```
/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `May I know what is the import function of this?` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Apologize for the confusion its originally "/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

My Plan is to create an script that can import csv from my local to google sheet using python the script that I posted is for exporting of spreadsheet.

Comment: I edited my sample script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to upload a CSV data to Google Drive and put it to Google Spreadsheet. is my understanding correct? Now, I found your new question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72268993/7108653 . In this case, your this question is the same as your new question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , Yes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From your reply, I would like to recommend populating your 2 same questions into one question.

Comment: Sure, we can focus on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72268993  Thank you @Tanaike